# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M-6,NaNH0.5V20.5H-6"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create two line charts with d3 in react but I keep getting this error and I don't know how to solve it. The line charts are supposed to be made with the epoch time on the X-axis and the health values on the yAxis(Disk_Free, Memory_Free).I've changed the dataset values into float values but I think there's something wrong with the time values. Im very new to d3 so any advice would be helpful.

This is my dataset

```
[

 {
   Health_id: 1,
   Epoch_Time: 1603959168.903983,
   Disk_Free: '86.2',
   Memory_Free: '1555480576',
   
 },
 {
   Health_id: 2,
   Epoch_Time: 1603959183.331211,
   Disk_Free: '86.2',
   Memory_Free: '1552396288',
   
  },
  {
   Health_id: 3,
   Epoch_Time: 1603959197.5066514,
   Disk_Free: '86.2',
   Memory_Free: '1565560832',
   
},
{
   Health_id: 4,
   Epoch_Time: 1603959211.6641965,
   Disk_Free: '86.2',
   Memory_Free: '1602510848',
  
  },
{
   Health_id: 5,
   Epoch_Time: 1603959225.8478744,
   Disk_Free: '86.2',
   Memory_Free: '1594617856',
   
},
]
```

My d3 code for line generation looks like this

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    const { data } = nextProps; //This is where I accept the above dataset and I try creating the line charts with it

    if(!data){
        return {};
    }
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([margin.left,width-margin.right]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height-margin.botton,margin.top])
    
    //Set Domains on Scales

    const timeDomain = d3.extent(data, d=>(d.Epoch_Time*1000))
    const healthID = d3.extent(data, d=>(d.Health_id))
    xScale.domain(timeDomain)
    yScale.domain(healthID)
    
    //Create and use line generator to plot the line charts

    const lineGenerator = d3.line().x(d=>xScale((d.Epoch_Time*1000)))
    const lines = [

        {
            path:lineGenerator.y((d)=>yScale((d.Disk_Free)))(data)
        },
        {
            path:lineGenerator.y((d)=>yScale((d.Memory_Free)))(data)
        },
       
    ];
    return {lines, xScale, yScale};
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="main-body">
            <h4 center>Line Chart Test</h4>
            <svg>
                <g>
                    {this.state.lines.map((d,i)=>{
                        if(i===0){
                            return <path d={d.path} fill="none" stroke="red" />
                        }
                        else{
                            return <path d={d.path} fill="none" stroke="blue" />
                        } 
           })}
                </g>
               
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}}export default Chart;
```

I don't get any line charts when I run the website and the error that it shows is:

```
      Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, 
      "….00000665251144,NaNL35.097628459…".
```

my svg path looks like this:

```
 <path d="M35.00203802950035,NaNL102.09192541055444,NaNL168.70615737356852,NaNL235.2960961666892,NaNL301.9796416583058,NaNL368.6469772068924,NaNL435.1701408263458,NaNL01.790251499806,NaNL568.4943668788065,NaNL635.0026281969162,NaN" fill="none"stroke="red">
</path>
```

Comment: Your yScale has an issue - logging it's domain and range reveals a problem. The range is `[NaN,someNumber]` - chances are your margin object doesn't have a property named `botton`: `range([height-margin.botton,margin.top])`. Though, given the size of Memory_Free values as compared against the domain, you might not get the line you are looking for once the scale range is fixed.

Comment: could you suggest any advice on how to generate a line properly? Like I said I'm very new to this so I can't think of any alternative.

Comment: Well, if you correct the typo in the range (and convert the strings to numbers as below) do you at least get a valid line with no `NaN`s ? If so, then it's merely a question of setting a proper domain, which is something separate from the error you are getting.

Comment: Yes, i have got a valid line but the domain cant be seen.

Comment: Good - now we can look at the domain. The domain is [1,5] - a value of 1 will be scaled to be equal to the first value in the range, a value of 5 will be scaled to be equal to the second value in the range. Since your data is outside of [1,5] for memory and disk, your line will be drawn outside your range. Considerably so, since disk is ~16x the upper limit of the scale's range and memory is orders of magnitude more. You'll likely want to set the domain for each line, in your setup, using different scales, with the domain equal to `d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.PropertyBeingScaled })`

Comment: ok so what youre saying is to manually code separate domains for the different Y values(disk free, memory free etc) right?and then generate the lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223882/discussion-between-mathew-pius-and-andrew-reid).

Comment: I will be back in a few minutes, but yes, you need to change the domain for each data series or create a new series, and that domain should reflect the extent of that series. If your two series were close in values you could get away with a single domain that reflected both data series, but you are scaling series where one series is millions of times greater than the other, to see something meaningful, you need to have separate domains (you could plot them with one domain, something like [0,2000000000] but it won't be very readable).

Comment: Alright I’ll give it a try.thank you

Comment: @AndrewReid: You should post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @PeterO. Most of the comments regard a solution a problem unrelated to the original question (which is due to a typo), my comments are more directed at what happens next in terms of proper scaling. Kind of feel that an answer based on the comments wouldn't really address the question directly. If OP still has comments later, I'll add something, chat was empty when I got there, so not sure if there are outstanding questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your Y values `Disk_Free` and `Memory_Free` are strings. You'll need to convert them to numbers first with e.g. `parseFloat`:

```
lineGenerator.y((d) => yScale(parseFloat(d.Disk_Free)))(data)

// ...

lineGenerator.y((d) => yScale(parseFloat(d.Memory_Free)))(data)
```